# How to make one side of a div pointy with CSS?

Tags: ios, css

I'm trying to create a pointy button like this:

[image: pointy button]

So far, I was only able to achieve this:

[image: round button]

I thought increasing the horizontal border-radius would make it sharp, but all it does it make the roundness longer.

**HTML**

```
<a class="button">Back</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;
    padding: 0 0.7em 0 1.4em;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    border-radius: 3em 0.4em 0.4em 3em / 1.5em 0.4em 0.4em 1.5em;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #fff,
        #ccc
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about it more, this is a more elegant solution that allows much more effective styling and the use of just one HTML element. Using this method, we can achieve the results in your concept completely.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Back</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.button {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 10px;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:0 8px 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 8px 8px 0;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:#3b3d3c;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-left:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top , #eee 0%,#bbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( top , #eee 0%,#bbb 100%);  
}
a.button:after {
    content:"";
     width:25px;
     height:25px;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient( left top , #eee 0%,#bbb 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left top , #eee 0%,#bbb 100%);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     top:5px;
     left:-14px;
     z-index:-1;
     border:1px solid  #666;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
a.button:after{
    border-left:0;
    left:-13px;
}
```

The last rule is for Chrome, which otherwise renders the result slightly differently.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to be using `border-radius` as that assigns a quarter-circle shape to each specified corner. Instead you hack it with specific `border-width` properties, as illustrated in this site: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

However I feel you're solving the problem the wrong way; what you're doing is best done using a background image, which is how the iOS-style Back buttons are implemented in iPhone-for-web stylesheets. If you need something resolution-independent then you can use SVG without penalty now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create such an effect using 2 elements side by side wrapped in the anchor tags.

```
<style type="text/css">
.arrow-left {
        width:0; 
        height:0; 
        border-top:30px solid transparent;
        border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
        border-right:30px solid orange; 
        float:left;
}
.button {
        float:left;
        height:60px;
        background:orange;
        width:50px;
        line-height:60px;
        font-weight:bold; 
        border-top-right-radius:8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
</style>

<a href='#'><div class="arrow-left"></div><div class="button">Back</div></a>
```

I'm not sure if it's the most refined solution, but it certainly looks the same as your concept art and functions as intended.

Comment: I will need a linear gradient so the element looks like a button. How do I apply a gradient to a CSS triangle?

Comment: You probably want to use `span` instead of `div` here, since you're not supposed to put "block" elements inside "inline" elements.