# Best way to create "arrow" in div

Tags: css, image, arrows

I'm in trying to create something that looks like the attached image, and am struggling with how to do this so it is responsive. I'd love a way to do this with css, but right now I'm just using images.

Ive seen where to make the points on the top, and was able to get it to go on the side, but I cannot find where to do the indent for the black section.

You can see the page here: [amazingmoves.com/dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKK8C.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774061/how-to-make-one-side-of-a-div-pointy-with-css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652877/css-how-to-make-rectangle-with-pointed-sides http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017502/how-can-i-create-div-with-a-pointed-top-with-css

Answer (score 0):

A sample.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.wrap{
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul *{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
li{
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}
li:before, li:after{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
li:before{
  top:0;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}
li:after{
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
li:nth-child(2):after, li:nth-child(2):before{
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
<li>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <a href="" class="more">More</a>
</li>
<li>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <a href="" class="more">More</a>
</li>
<li>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <a href="" class="more">More</a>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/rmcy7dtq/